# How do I do commit a renamed file with case-sensitive using TortoiseGit?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, file-rename, tortoisegit

I am trying a sample project to rename a file using Eclipse. First, I did a commit and pushed to GitHub. The file was `Samplemain.java`. If I rename that file to `SampleMain.java` and if I try to commit the renamed file using TortoiseGit, I'm unable to commit. Instead, it's showing an error with a small dialog.

Please let me know the solutions for renaming files with case-sensitive in Git.
I am using Windows, the error dialog is shown below.
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of what the error dialog is? Also, this is important, are you using Windows, or Linux or Mac? Windows treats file paths as case-insensitive, while Linux and Mac are both case-sensitive in regards to paths.

Comment: Hi Cupcake, I use windows, please can find above error dialog.

Comment: Also, new versions of TortoiseGit seem to now have this problem -- as long as you use the Git rename command from the start, it should just work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem with TortoiseGit, not with Git itself. If you commit using the command line it will work, I checked it now. Note that renaming still takes 2 `git mv` commands, but only one `git commit`, as it should.

Another alternative is to rename the file on GitHub: when editing a file on GitHub notice at the top that you can change the name. After that you can pull from it.

Comment: Hi Janos, First, great thanks to you. you said the same, what I am thinking is. May be rename not works in TortoiseGit. Is it possible to apply the rename to all dependent files If I do rename the file name on GitHub itself? If it helps me, it would be great. The same thing If I do commit and push using egit, it works great.

Comment: Hello Janos, would you please do positive vote for my question. Because, I am newbie to StackExchange, also I have score less than 15.

Comment: Hi, renaming on GitHub itself should be a last resort. GitHub doesn't know what kind of project it is and so it cannot rename dependent files. That would be refactoring, and only your build tool can do that correctly.

Comment: @Satyarao.K you have to ***earn*** upvotes, by writing good questions and answer. It's not a good idea to beg for them.

Comment: Hello Janos, I think you don't need to do commit by two way process, if you use egit. I did this way, I did not get any problems.

Comment: modifying on Github was useful

Answer (score 3):

Run following command in Windows command line (MINGW console). It should fix the case detection problem.

```
git config core.ignorecase false
```

Comment: this is corect answer, spot on

Comment: This only half solves it -- when using simple Explorer renames anyway. When this is enabled, and you do an Explorer rename, it notices that there's a *new file*, with the new casing -- not that the old one was renamed to that new casing. So the repo ends up having both versions! Which show up in Github and the like, but not in Windows explorer. In that case, you can fix it by renaming it to `name_`, committing, then renaming it back and committing. (you can also do this for the parent folder, to apply for all descendents; however, then you can mess up the file history for the other files)

Answer (score 0):

Two-stage rename... name it to something like 'z.tmp' then back to the name your really want.

I know with Subversion I have to commit between two-step renames, but with Mercurial I don't.

Not sure if Git needs it or not.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks for your time. I know that it would need 2 step process in svn. Please let me know in git only.

Comment: If you use "Git rename" in tortoisegit, from the start, that's the only operation you need to do. (in the latest versions, since they fixed that)

However, if you renamed it with Windows explorer, you need to do the two-stage rename as you suggest. (or some other solution -- see my other answer)

Answer (score 0):

There's a utility made for this apparently: https://github.com/tawman/git-unite

I haven't been able to try it myself yet, as the author doesn't provide the final exe files, and I had an issue when trying to run the build script. But it seems to be a utility that would solve this issue more easily.

It searches for name-casing mismatches between repo and folders, and updates the repo to match the folder, letting you then commit with only one version of the files. So just change the names in Windows explorer to what you want, then run the utility, I believe. (maybe followed by a commit -- not sure)